# preserve dates whilst applying pandas to_numeric function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set the data in a pandas dataframe to numeric with pd.to_numeric, but when I run the code the datetime dates get overwritten with NaN.

Initial data:

```
           Header1       Header2      Header3      Header4
Row1     01-01-2020   15-01-2020   01-02-2020   15-02-2020
Row2          123           456         789           246
Row3          321           654         987           642
Row4          123           456         789           246
```

Result:

```
           Header1       Header2      Header3      Header4
Row1           NaN           NaN         NaN           NaN
Row2          123           456         789           246
Row3          321           654         987           642
Row4          123           456         789           246
```

How can I selectively use pd.to_numeric to convert the data to numeric but preserve the datetime dates that already exist? Cheers

Comment: Is the Date is columns ?

Comment: @ YOBEN_S:   No, the date is part of the data, and it is the first (top) row.

Comment: what do you get as result for your current case if the input is `00123` instead of `123` ?

Comment: The date should not be in the data part but in the columns one. Any further processing will be complex if you leave them in the data. Caveat emptor...

Comment: @ Serge: thanks, but this is only example data representative of my much larger dataset which has different headers and contains some dates as well. I can't change the data set that I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flag `errors='ignore'` in `pd.to_numeric`. Here is example:

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd 

date = datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 3, 14, 15)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['01-01-2020', date, '1.0', '2', -3])

df[0] = pd.to_numeric(df[0], errors='ignore')
```

The output will be:

```
                     0
0           01-01-2020
1  2020-02-03 14:15:00
2                  1.0
3                    2
4                   -3
```

However, you should be careful while ignoring errors. I would suggest to separate `datetime` columns if it is possible.